# local temporary variable assignment

Tags: grouping, variable

I am sure this has been asked many times already in many different ways, but can't get any of what I found so far to work. So here we go:

I am using the following code (that I once found on here somewhere) to globally toggle the rendering of tikz pictures:

```
\newif\ifshowtikz
\showtikztrue
% \showtikzfalse % <---- comment/uncomment that line

\let\oldtikzpicture\tikzpicture \let\oldendtikzpicture\endtikzpicture

\renewenvironment{tikzpicture}{%
  \ifshowtikz\expandafter\oldtikzpicture
  \else
  \fi }{%
  \ifshowtikz\oldendtikzpicture%
  \else
  \fi }
```

Now, I also use tikz pictures in certain places where I always want them to render. For these places I use the following macro:

```
\newcommand{\propbox}[1]{
    \tikz{\node[
    draw,shade,rounded corners=0.1cm, top color=teal!30,bottom color=teal!80,blur shadow={shadow blur steps=5}] (A) {#1};}
}
```

I would like to to put a conditional into that `propbox` macro that is sensitive to the global `showtikz` value, like so:

```
if not showtikz:
   temp = showtikz
   showtikz = True
   # probbox code
   showtikz = temp
else:
   # probbox code
```

Something like that. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you have to deal separately with the `\tikz` command and the `{tikzpicture}` environment. To get rid of `\tikz` commands, you can use `\let\tikz\@gobble` which redefines the command `\tikz` to just delete its argument. To get rid of `{tikzpicture}` environments, you can let it equal to the comment environment from the `verbatim` package.

To define the `\propbox`, we restore the definitions of both inside of a group, put in the definition of `\propbox` and then end the group so our temporarily restored definitions go out of scope.

Here's the full code with an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\propbox}[1]{
    \bgroup % start local group
    % ensure {tikzpicture} environment is not a comment
    \let\tikzpicture\save@tikzpicture
    \let\endtikzpicture\save@endtikzpicture
    % Rather than restoring the value of \tikz shorter to use \save@tikz directly
    \save@tikz{\node[
    draw,shade,rounded corners=0.1cm, top color=teal!30,bottom color=teal!80] (A) {#1};}
    \egroup % The definitions go out of scope here so if tikz is not being displayed,
    % {tikzpicture} goes back to being a comment
}

% Save copies of tikz commands
\let\save@tikzpicture\tikzpicture
\let\save@endtikzpicture\endtikzpicture
\let\save@tikz\tikz

% A no-op defintion of \tikz that correctly gobbles argument 
% whether delimited by braces or semicolon
\def\gobbletikz{
    \@ifnextchar\bgroup % Is the argument brace delimited?
        {\@gobble}     % If the next character is an open brace, \@gobble suffices
        {\gobbletikz@} % Otherwise, it's semicolon delimited
}
% gobble until the next semicolon
\def\gobbletikz@#1;{}

% set tikz commands to be no-ops
\def\hidetikzpictures{
    \let\tikzpicture\comment
    \let\endtikzpicture\endcomment
    \let\tikz\gobbletikz
}

% restore tikz commands
\def\showtikzpictures{
    \let\tikzpicture\save@tikzpicture
    \let\endtikzpicture\save@endtikzpicture
    \let\tikz\save@tikz
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\hidetikzpictures
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [draw] (0,0){hidden};
\end{tikzpicture}
\propbox{shown even though hidetikzpictures}
\tikz{\node[draw] (0,0) {also hidden};}
\tikz \node[draw]{also also hidden};
\vskip 12pt

\showtikzpictures
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [draw] (0,0){shown};
\end{tikzpicture}
\propbox{shown either way}
\tikz{\node[draw] (0,0) {also shown};}
\tikz \node[draw]{also also shown};
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is `save@` just a normal substring or is it a keyword with semantics?
And where does `\save@tikz` in `\save@tikz{\node[` coem from? Is it in one of the headers?

Comment: `save@` has no semantics, it's just supposed to indicate that it's where I'm saving things. The `\save@tikz` macro is where I've saved the original value of the `\tikz` macro.  It's just a little bit shorter to use `\save@tikz` directly rather than saying `\let\tikz\save@tikz` and using `\tikz`, but it's equivalent.

Comment: I edited the code to add comments that hopefully clarify things.

Comment: Please note, that this won't cover cases like `\tikz \draw (1,0) -- (0,1);` (i.e. `\tikz` macro without argument braces) …

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot you could do that. I can add a check for that case.

Comment: @Tobi Should be fixed.